# Getting rails tagging plugins to work makes me Hulk-angry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, documentation, tagging

I spent all my time yesterday trying to get ANY Rails tagging plugin to work. While installation was straightforward, I have to say the amount of documentation on how to use any of these plugins was dismal at best...

For the record, I tried:

is_taggable
acts_as_taggable_on
acts_as_taggable_on_steroids
acts_as_taggable_redux

In every instance, the documentation consisted of something like this:

1. install
2. ***undefined magic*** <---(This is where I fell over, What do I put in my Models, Views and Controllers to make your awesome plugin work? Please tell me!)
3. Check out all these cool features!

With all of the plugins, I'd ended up dealing with errors like:

```
NoMethodError in ItemsController#create undefined method `tag_list=' for #<Item:0x47fe848>
```

I looked up the issues raised on the respective plugin's websites and found that I'm definitely not the only one with these issues. But author support/explanation was not forthcoming even though most of these issues had been raised a while back.

I understand that if I was some kind of Rails guru I could probably get the plugin to work. But I'm not. In my frustration I've decided to just roll my own tagging implementation which seems stupid considering there's so many plugins for tagging available out there...

I also have to say I'm a bit concerned that most of these plugins haven't been maintained in a while. Which makes me wonder if they'll be brought over to Rails 3.

If anyone knows of a tagging plugin for Rails that really works and is easy to implement, please let me know (and if you could point me to a decent tutorial I will give you my undying gratitude as well as some amazing pieces of fluff I found in my pocket just then...)

Otherwise, let this be a plea from all those beginner/intermediate Rails programmers out there to the Rails gods who make and maintain plugins... "We love your work, but please, please provide more documentation!"

Comment: +1 for ..."makes me Hulk-angry".

Comment: I typed something similar into Google out of rage and laughed when I got this. Thank you for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used [mbleigh's acts-as-taggable-on](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), and the basic procedure goes:

1. Add `config.gem "acts-as-taggable-on"` to environment.rb
2. Run `rake gems:install`
3. Run `script/generate acts_as_taggable_on_migration`

   - Do any customizations on the migration you might want (you probably won't need to).
4. Run the migration, `rake db:migrate`
5. Add `acts_as_taggable_on :your_desired_tag_names` to your tagged model (pluralized).

   - I.e. Photo model has `:colors` tag.
   - If you are getting a `NoMethodError`, you *may* have skipped this step.
6. To set the models tags, use `photo.color_list = 'abc, 123, def, 456'`
7. Save the model: `photo.save`
8. List the tags: `photo.colors`

   - You might have to reload the model from the database for the `photo.colors` method to be available.

Check out the [acts-as-taggable-on readme](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) for more instructions/examples.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! It worked... For some strange reason when I was trying this plugin out yesterday it didn't understand when I tried to add acts_as_taggable_on :tags in the model. It threw all kinds of crazy errors and I couldn't progress past that point...

I don't know what, I don't know how. But it works now and I'm really grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Crazy World!

I also managed to get acts_as_taggable_on_steroids working today...

The missing link was that you needed to add this to ApplicationHelper:

> include TagsHelper

This was mentioned in the readme but only under the "Tag Clouds" section so it wasn't clear that you needed to add it for any of the methods to be recognized in the first place...

Comment: Yes unfortunately it seems that the author of the post has removed their old blog platform and posts. I checked but couldn't find a google cache of it either... I've removed the link for now, thanks for pointing it out